# uk vps server route to thailand?

Tags: centos, performance, vps, route, page-speed

I'm just a Javascript developer using node.js...

My host has got me a vps sever in england. I have had someone test my site loading in england and it is lightning fast. I've also had someone test in italy and they said its almost instant. Right now I'm in Thailand and it is quite slow it plods along and sometimes pauses to think about things..

I have been looking at https://www.varnish-cache.org/.

But, I think it makes sense; that my requests to the server are going through a massive route and back again with the response so it takes time!

Can I get a near-by server to make the route shorter with out having to make a copy of my server? I know not much/nothing... I need to talk to my host about this.

Update

my host has a main website for accessing cpannel hiswebsite1.com, if he had the download mirrors hiswebsite2.com near here would that help?

Comment: Just so you know, the smartcard website your so proud of, it's domain has expired :(

Comment: You really haven't given us much to go on. There are lots of technologies available to help speed up delivery of a website but _you_ need to figure out what exactly the problem is. Once you've done that then finding a solution will be easir.

Comment: Thanks Iain, I know about that but forgot to remove it from here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I get a near-by server to make the route shorter with out having to make a copy of my 
>   server?

Yes. How much work that is depends on how - ah - much - ah dynamic it is and whether your host supports georouting. Note that this does rule out 99% of the hosts. Very few can do anycast base geo located routing.

It is also possible that with a little more knowledge of what you are doing you could reprogram your site to be faster. Thailand to England is not that much a latency unless you do a LOT of ajax requests one after the next.

I would start getting access to a machine located in thailand and then use standard (what every developer should learn to call him one) profiling tools to find out where your time is spent. Glimpse for example (although that most likely does not exist for Node.js) is a tool that can give me a nice timeline of events on a website so I can see WHERE the time is spent.

If image loading is slow - which is also possible - that one is solvable. Move images off from your own machine into a CDN - CDN's, at least the not totally crappy ones, are georouting, so thailand wil lbe served from a closer location.

> I know not much/nothing... I need to talk to my host about this.

So what you do here? I mean, you already know that you need to talk to your host. What are we supposed to tell you? That you, as a web developer, should at one point have read some basics about the technologies you use?

You likely do get hit by latency (not avoidable) and a very bad optimized website programming.